# How to generate HTML file from Java class without hard coding HTML tags in the class?

Tags: java, html

I want to generate one HTML file form a String content.
But I do not want to hard code HTML tags (like `<html>`, `<body>`, `<tr>`, `<td>` etc.) in the Java class. In the same time, I also do not want to use any third party library for it.

It is a simple Java project (there is no web project flavor).

In my mind, I am thinking of using a properties file to configure all HTML tags and use those properties in my Java class.

If anyone has any other way to do this, please suggest me through a simple example.

Comment: Try using HTML templates and replace your content to that template based on your need. like http://freemarker.org/

Comment: https://jsoup.org/

Comment: Care to elaborate on 1) how you expect to generate some HTML without hardcoding any HTML tags; 2) why third-party libraries are out of the question; and 3) how you expect properties files to help with issue #1?

Comment: Make html template file, read this file in java, write out your class data to template (at specific positions) and save it. This way is simple just for simple class. If your class is complex (inheritance, implementation, subclass inside...) you will work harder and harder!

Comment: @KevinAnderson; 1) I am trying to avoid the html tag hard coded in the java class because in future there may be the requirement of any other format like: csv, xml . So that there need not to be updating the java class again and again later.

Comment: @KevinAnderson; 
2)if there are any free source libraries available, i am ok with that(but manual is preferable).
3)I was thinking of using properties file so that the html tag will be mentioned there as name-value pair and i can retrieve that in my class. So for any changes required in future; no need to touch the source code.

Comment: This "String content" you speak of?  Is this some sort of well-structured data (like, for example, employee records with Id#, Name, Department #, Job #, etc.) that you want to merge into an HTML "skeleton"?  And the data format will be relatively stable but the HTML might change from time to time?

Answer (score 0):

I've been experimenting along these lines for one of my projects (producing an image of a receipt, going through HTML/CSS because wkhtmltopdf can render it as a PNG). I think you will find that trying to abstract your string generator to handle potential future output of CSV, XML, etc. will over-complicate your method. I have objects right now that I deal with via JSON, XML, and HTML, and they all require different approaches. For JSON, I rely on Spring's conversion. For XML, I use JAXB. For HTML, I have been doing what a couple of people mentioned in comments with templates.

e.g.

```
String template = "<html><head/><body><h1>Hello %s</h1></body></html>";
System.out.println(String.format(template, "World");
```

As also suggested in the comments, you could load that template string from a file, but this will become complicated very quickly, such as if you have objects within your first object which need to generate their own HTML:

```
public Class Container{
    private String name;
    private OtherClass other;
    public convertToHtml(){
        String template = "<html><head/><body><h1>Hello %s. Other: %s</h1></body></html>";
        return String.format(template, name, other.convertToHtml());
    }
}
public Class OtherClass{
    private String stuff;
    public convertToHtml(){
        String template = "<span>%s</span>";
        return String.format(template, stuff);
    }
}
```